# How to align two items to the right, without doing manual height/margin calculations?

Tags: css, positioning, alignment

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/HXH5Z/3/embedded/result/) demonstrates the problem.

[image]

I'm trying to align an image and a button to the right, on two separate lines, as a joint unit. I created a wrapper div ("right-stuff"), with position:relative, so I can use position:absolute on its child, the button.

The problem is I don't know of a good way to align the button to the right without hurting the height calculations.

What I did is give it `position:absolute` and `right:0`, but this removes it from the flow, and causes the container ("right-stuff") not to include it - see how the red background doesn't reach it, although it "should".

Another problem is that the next item in the flow after "right-stuff" will need a margin-top to be in the correct position, or otherwise I have to either give "right-stuff" a width I calculate myself, or an artifical margin (that takes into account the button height). Too much knowledge here.

Is there a better way to get both items to act as a coherent unit, that is "right aligned", but without taking things out of the flow?

Obviously this is not the first time someone has asked this question, but I haven't found an answer here that addresses these specific concerns without ugly hacks (like manually adding a margin-bottom equal to the button's height).

**Edit**: text-align is a decent solution (better than what I thought of anyway). One caveat: It assumes the button is indeed textual, and doesn't work on the image itself. This is ok in my example because the image is the widest thing in the container - but what if I had another element in the container that was wider than the image? How would I keep the image aligned to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since both of those elements (`img` and `button`) are `inline-block` you can simply use `text-align: right`.

Comment: You're right - this works because the image is larger than the button. I'll use this for now. Any ideas for how to solve it if the button can also be larger, or it might be an image, or we have some more items in the mix there (all of which have to be right-aligned within the container)?

Comment: Hmm.. I fail to see why it wouldn't work if the button was the larger element (instead of the image)?

Comment: Saw your comment below, yes, text-align affects all elements that aren't `display: block`. And since you can turn any element into any display it works on all elements (but by default on images and buttons as they aren't block).

Comment: Here, the image is not aligned to the right in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/HXH5Z/8/embedded/result/

Comment: Wait, so what kind of display would be appropriate here? `inline-block` with `clear:both`?

Comment: That's because it isn't an image, it's a div. If you intend to wrap your elements in divs (which are block), you need to set them to inline-block. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/HXH5Z/9/

Comment: And this places them on separate lines if their combined width is too small. I even tried adding `clear:both`, trying to get them into separate lines, but something is not right here: http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/HXH5Z/12/

Comment: If the div isn't set to the same width as the widest element in it, the button and the img will sit on the same line (since they're inline-block). To avoid this, one of the elements needs to be set to display: block; and that would have to be the widest of the two elements. If you don't know which element is widest and can't set the container to the same width as the widest element you'd need to display them all block and float them right as well as clear: right. Here are three examples: http://jsfiddle.net/PYQuw/ and http://jsfiddle.net/PYQuw/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/PYQuw/2/

Comment: You sure get the points for the answer & comments - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with text-align right?

```
<div id="nContainer">
    <div id="nRight-stuff">
        <div id="nRight-img">
            <img src="http://sharecare.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/cute-animals-1.jpg?w=490" />
        </div>
        <button id="nRight-btn">A right aligned button</button>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both" />
</div>

#nRight-stuff {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXH5Z/5/)

Answer (score 0):

check out the editted fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HXH5Z/4/

basically i've just brought the button back in the flow, but enclosed it in a div, aligning the content (text-align) to the right. The same could be achieved by just adding the `text-align: right` rule to the `#right-stuff` div, but i don't know if you also want the image to be aligned to the right inside that div...

Comment: Will text-align work on the image? I want the image aligned to the right as well. This currently works because the image is wider than the button, and is text. What if the button was an image, or we had another element in the container that's wider than the image (but we still wanted the image to be right-aligned)?

Comment: yup that also works, checkout http://jsfiddle.net/HXH5Z/7/ the funny thing is that css aligns pretty much everything when using the text-align property, including images, buttons, anchors etc.

Comment: Wait, you replaced the background-image with an actual image tag (which I was taught is a "no no" usually ... e.g. it will interfere with spriting). When I turn this back to the background-image div, the image is not right-aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/HXH5Z/10/

Comment: You need to set the div to display: inline-block; block elements are not affected by text-align.

Comment: well, if it's an image, than it's an image, so you _should_ use an image tag. A background should regularly only be used if it's a background (hence the name ;)). But if you definitely wanna go that way, just position the background (background-position: top right;), checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HXH5Z/13/